# Python - How to read a csv files separated by commas which have commas within the values?

Tags: python, csv

The file has an URL which contain commas within it. For example:
~oref=https://tuclothing.tests.co.uk/c/Girls/Girls_Underwear_Socks&Tights?INITD=GNav-CW-GrlsUnderwear&title=Underwear,+Socks+&+Tights

Between Underwear and +Socks there is a comma which is making my life not easy.

Is there a way to indicate to the reader(Pandas, CSV reader..etc) that the whole URL is just one value?

This is a bigger sample with columns and values:

```
Event Time,User ID,Advertiser ID,TRAN Value,Other Data,ORD Value,Interaction Time,Conversion ID,Segment Value 1,Floodlight Configuration,Event Type,Event Sub-Type,DBM Auction ID,DBM Request Time,DBM Billable Cost (Partner Currency),DBM Billable Cost (Advertiser Currency),
1.47E+15,CAESEKoMzQamRFTrkbdTDT5F-gM,2934701,,~oref=https://tuclothing.tests.co.uk/c/NewIn/NewIn_Womens?q=%3AnewArrivals&page=2&size=24,4.60E+12,1.47E+15,1,0,940892,CONVERSION,POSTCLICK,,,0,0,
1.47E+15,CAESEKQhGXdLq0FitBKF5EPPfgs,2934701,,~oref=https://tuclothing.tests.co.uk/c/Women/Women_Accessories?INITD=GNav-WW-Accesrs&q=%3AnewArrivals&title=Accessories&mkwid=sv5biFf2y_dm&pcrid=90361315613&pkw=leather%20bag&pmt=e&med=Search&src=Google&adg=Womens_Accessories&kw=leather+bag&cmp=TU_Women_Accessories&adb_src=4,4.73E+12,1.47E+15,1,0,940892,CONVERSION,POSTCLICK,,,0,0,
1.47E+15,CAESEEpNRaLne21k6juip9qfAos,2934701,,num=16512910;~oref=https://tuclothing.tests.co.uk/,1,1.47E+15,1,0,940892,CONVERSION,POSTCLICK,,,0,0,
1.47E+15,CAESEJ3a2YRrPSSeeRUFHDSoXNQ,2934701,,~oref=https://tuclothing.tests.co.uk/c/Girls/Girls_Underwear_Socks&Tights?INITD=GNav-CW-GrlsUnderwear&title=Underwear,+Socks+&+Tights,8.12E+12,1.47E+15,1,0,940892,CONVERSION,POSTCLICK,,0,0,0
1.47E+15,CAESEGmwaNjTvIrQ3MoIvqiRC8U,2934701,,~oref=https://tuclothing.tests.co.uk/login/checkout,1.75E+12,1.47E+15,1,0,940892,CONVERSION,POSTCLICK,,,0,0,
1.47E+15,CAESEM3G-Nh6Q0OhboLyOhtmtiI,2934701,,~oref=https://3984747.fls.doubleclick.net/activityi;~oref=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tests.co.uk%2Fshop%2Fgb%2Fgroceries%2Ffrozen-%2Fbeef--pork---lamb,3.74E+12,1.47E+15,1,0,940892,CONVERSION,POSTCLICK,,,0,0,
1.47E+15,CAESENlK7oc-ygl637Y2is3a90c,2934701,,~oref=https://tuclothing.tests.co.uk/,5.10E+12,1.47E+15,1,0,940892,CONVERSION,POSTCLICK,,,0,0,
```

Comment: Do you control the output of the csv file? Or is this file generated by a third-party which you do not have control over the exporting process?

Comment: Sadly, It's generated by a third-party which I don't have control.

Comment: If you know the data type of each column, then you can check for each comma whether the upcoming character belongs to the right type (of the next column) if not, then the comma belongs to content.

Comment: "tuclothing.tests.co.uk’s server DNS address could not be found."

Comment: I'm afraid you would have to preprocess your data first (escaping or quoting "wrong" delimiters).

Comment: I am unable to determine where the url ends. I noticed, however, that all lines end with `CONVERSION,POSTCLICK,,,0,0,` with the exception being the row that is causing trouble which ends with `CONVERSION,POSTCLICK,,0,0,` Note 2 adjacent commas rather than 3. This leads me to thin that data for the columns is being shifted prior to your acquiring them and some data would end up in the wrong column and your program won't work properly.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, in this case, the only comma which you are having issues with is located in a URL.  You could run your `csv` file through a preprocessor method which strips out commas in your URLs or URL encode them.

Personally, I would opt for the URL encoding method which will convert the comma to `%2E`, this way you don't have a comma in your URL when you start reading your csv row values, yet the URL still retains its working link to the reference/destination page.

If you had this issue with other fields (not a URL), or in other unknown/random locations in the csv row, then the solution would not be easy at all.  But since you know exactly where the issue is occurring each time, you could perform a static lookup for that character and replace if found in that particular field.